# Optimizing away log function calls depending on global log level

Tags: c++, logging, optimization

I am a member of a university team designing a nanosatellite.
We decided to implement our own (more lite) logging library to use, instead of, say, Google's `glog`, `spdlog`, `plog` and `Boost::Log`.

- The concept of different log levels is introduced, as a means of dividing the log messages into subcategories, according to their severity and whether they were expected to occur.
- Furthermore, there will be a "global log level" that can be defined.
  Everything less severe than the severity set as the global log level, will *not* be logged.

Due to obvious restrictions, it is imperative that log calls below the global log level get optimized away at compile time.

The first attempt was something like this (single header file):
log levels:

```cpp
// We can set the global log level by defining one of these
#if defined LOGLEVEL_TRACE
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::trace
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_DEBUG
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::debug
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_INFO
[...]
#else
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::disabled
#endif
```

the levels themselves are `enum` members:

```cpp
enum LogLevel {
        trace = 32, // Very detailed information, useful for tracking the individual steps of an operation
        debug = 64, // General debugging information
        info = 96, // Noteworthy or periodical events
[...]
};
```

A `operator<<` overload for better readability:

```cpp
template <class T>
Logger::LogEntry& operator<<(Logger::LogEntry& entry, const T value) {
    etl::to_string(value, entry.message, entry.format, true);

    return entry;
}
```

And the macro-`constexpr` sorcery to make the compiler do what we want:

```cpp
#define LOG(level)
    if (Logger::isLogged(level)) \
        if (Logger::LogEntry entry(level); true) \
            entry
// [...]
static constexpr bool isLogged(LogLevelType level) {
        return static_cast<LogLevelType>(LOGLEVEL) <= level;
    }
```

There were many issues with this code (see the [MR discussion](https://gitlab.com/acubesat/obc/ecss-services/merge_requests/44#7f70288c0af0c93596020b4a0cf98732bd506151) for more).

- A call operator to the `enum LogLevel` has been added to return a new `static LogEntry`.
- It is `inline`d to force `const` propagation at `-O1`.
- Two `LogEntry` `enums` have been created.
- The second one is a `nop` with everything `inline`.
- `if constexpr` syntax has been added.

and more (see [here](https://gitlab.com/acubesat/obc/ecss-services/merge_requests/44#note_206390254) and below for justification.)

That's the (chopped) state of the code currently:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

#define LOGLEVEL_EMERGENCY

#if defined LOGLEVEL_TRACE
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::trace
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_DEBUG
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::debug
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_INFO
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::info
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_NOTICE
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::notice
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_WARNING
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::warning
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_ERROR
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::error
#elif defined LOGLEVEL_EMERGENCY
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::emergency
#else
#define LOGLEVEL Logger::disabled
#endif

#define LOG_TRACE     (LOG<Logger::trace>())
#define LOG_DEBUG     (LOG<Logger::debug>())
#define LOG_INFO      (LOG<Logger::info>())
#define LOG_NOTICE    (LOG<Logger::notice>())
#define LOG_WARNING   (LOG<Logger::warning>())
#define LOG_ERROR     (LOG<Logger::error>())
#define LOG_EMERGENCY (LOG<Logger::emergency>())

class Logger {
public:

    Logger() = delete;

    typedef uint8_t LogLevelType;

    enum LogLevel : LogLevelType {
        trace = 32,
        debug = 64,
        info = 96,
        notice = 128,
        warning = 160,
        error = 192,
        emergency = 254,
        disabled = 255, 
    };

    enum class NoLogEntry {};

    struct LogEntry {
        std::string message = "";
        LogLevel level;

        explicit LogEntry(LogLevel level);

        ~LogEntry();

        LogEntry(LogEntry const&) = delete;

        template <class T>
        Logger::LogEntry& operator<<(const T value) noexcept {
            message.append(value);

            return *this;
        }

        Logger::LogEntry& operator<<(const std::string& value);
    };

    static constexpr bool isLogged(LogLevelType level) {
        return static_cast<LogLevelType>(LOGLEVEL) <= level;
    }

    static void log(LogLevel level, std::string & message);
};

template <Logger::LogLevel level>
constexpr inline auto LOG() {
    if constexpr (Logger::isLogged(level)) {
        return Logger::LogEntry(level);
    } else {
        return Logger::NoLogEntry();
    }
};

template <typename T>
[[maybe_unused]] constexpr Logger::NoLogEntry operator<<(const Logger::NoLogEntry noLogEntry, T value) {
    return noLogEntry;
}

int main() {
    LOG_NOTICE << "I am getting optimized away!";
    LOG_EMERGENCY << "I am not getting optimized away, and rightfully so";

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in e.g.[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/lnLFy-), the `LOG_NOTICE` is getting optimized away at `-O1`.

Do you have any suggestions?

I've come across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887822/c-c-logging-facility-that-supports-conditional-function-calls-depending-on-log), but it isn't relevant since I've opted from a custom, from-scratch logging library implementation.

Comment: Firstly, this is more a code review question.   Second your code is "chopped" so much that it would be difficult for anyone to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: @Peter you're probably right about the nature of this question, I've cross-posted it there too.
It isn't "that" chopped, only thing I changed was I replaced `etl`'s string and relevant functions used with `std::string` and `std::string.append`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not believe in global patterns like global logger or the singleton pattern; nor I feel that there is a strong need for such a compile time logger optimizations. As long as the message isn't composed (converting `("The ratio is {}:{}", 20, 50)` into `"The ratio is 20:50"`) when it isn't needed you won't suffer from performance issues due to logging.

In fact, I'd say you shouldn't optimize it in compile time as otherwise you cannot configure your logger without recompiling. If you have to recompile your whole program just to adjust logger configuration that will be a debug hell since it might change behavior due to recompiling and it will be especially bad in cases when you want to test your program on a user devise that doesn't have the developer environment.

My advise is to use a configurable logger class whose instance is passed to all major components of your project. And provide it with a simple message function that processes the logging messages. I wrote an example (just make the message level into an enum or something).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class CGlobalLogger
{
    public:
    void Print(const std::string& str)
    {
        std::lock_guard g(m_mutex);
        std::cout << str;
    }
    int  GetMessageLevel()
    {
        return m_messageLevel;
    }
    private:
    int        m_messageLevel = 5;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

void Print(std::stringstream& ss){};

template<typename... Args, typename Arg>
void Print(std::stringstream& ss, Arg&& arg,  Args&&... args)
{
    ss << arg;
    Print(ss, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


class CLocalLogger
{
    public:
    CLocalLogger() = default;
    CLocalLogger(std::shared_ptr<CGlobalLogger> global_logger, std::string local_name)
    {
        m_log           = std::move(global_logger);
        m_local_name    = std::move(local_name);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void Log(int messageLevel, Args&&... args)
    {
        if(messageLevel < m_log->GetMessageLevel())
        {
            return;
        }

        std::stringstream ss;

        Print(ss, m_local_name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        m_log->Print(ss.str());
    }
    private:
    std::string                     m_local_name;
    std::shared_ptr<CGlobalLogger>  m_log;
};

int main()
{
    CLocalLogger logger(std::make_shared<CGlobalLogger>(), "main: ");

    logger.Log(7, "Hello World! ", 5, " ", 7.);
    logger.Log(3, "I won't be printed... ", 5, "abs");

    return 0;
}
```

As a bonus you can manipulate your local logger so you can identify who printed the message which can be hard in certain situations with a global logger. Say, you have a common `class A` and you have a print inside it. So you give to each instance of `class A` a local logger with a unique local name, then you can tell whose instance of `class A` prints the message in the log and not just that the `class A` prints it.

P.S. there are certain low level logging that should not be present in any release versions but usually you can simply comment them away unless you deal with a large project in which case you hide them behind a define or something.

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but perhaps I should have emphasized a bit more on the scope of the project.
This might go into a nanosatellite, thus we are talking about limited resources (e.g. memory/processing power).
This means a couple things:
First, no `mutex`es.
Second, messages not to be logged have to be optimized away, because they will take up precious size in memory either way (the utility will be heavily used, so there are going to be a lot of messages).
Third, this also means that there won't be such thing as a "user device".
In fact, patches will be done with binary diff.

Comment: @xlxs satellite itself is a "user device" in the sense that you cannot compile the program on it. What kind of hardware you have on it anyways? x486 processor? P.S., messages take static memory if they aren't composed and won't be loaded into cache.